# What does the “raw value” of the spin-up time in SMART parameters actually mean?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I have an offer to buy a used HGST HUS724020ALA640. The seller sent a screenshot of SMART parameters that are made using CrystalDiskInfo. I have checked these parameters and they are in the reference state (or close to it), except for the raw value of spin-up time:

| ID | Attribute Name | Current | Worst | Threshold | Raw-value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03 | spin-up time | 126 | 126 | 24 | 00A011EE01F0 |

**Additional information**

This hard drive was manufactured in 2016, the operating time is 45,321 hours and the number of power-ups is 29 times (Server usage).

**Question**

According to [S.M.A.R.T. Attribute: Spin-Up Time](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9103) is defined as:

> Spin-Up Time S.M.A.R.T. parameter indicates an average time (in **milliseconds** or **seconds**) of spindle spinup (from zero RPM (Revolutions Per Minute) to fully operational).

However, the value 00A011EE01F0 (687495578096 in dec) is too large to be the number of seconds or milliseconds.

What does the raw value of the spin-up time actually mean?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're buying a used HDD? Unless you're very hard up (understandable), HDDs are too cheap to risk buying one that's had some use and could go anyday.

Comment: @HashimAziz We can really say that a given disk with such parameters (operating time and spin-up time) can it fail at any time?
The seller asked for a price of $ 37, it seemed to me that this was a good offer

Comment: @PavelDev $37 for a 2TB SATA drive whose model dates back to 2013 (9 years ago) seems like a bad investment. Pay $10 or $20 more and you can get a brand new 2TB SATA drive with a warranty and a better lifespan. Buy this used stuff and you will most likely just get 1 year or so of use and such. Don’t pinch pennies on storage; don’t buy used storage.

Comment: Raw values mean whatever the manufacturer wants them to mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spin-up time is a weird parameter with weird values. Most manufacturers
treat it as optional and its values vary between them.
Usually, the values go backwards, as described below.

[S.M.A.R.T. Attribute: Spin-Up Time](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9103)
says this:

> Spin-Up Time S.M.A.R.T. parameter indicates an average time (in
> milliseconds or seconds) of spindle spinup (from zero RPM (Revolutions
> Per Minute) to fully operational).
>
> **The low value means it takes too long for the hard disk to a fully
> operational state**.

Thus a small value means a long spin-up time, but
a large value means a short spin-up time.

The nonsense enormous value that you see may mean either :

- That you have an ultra-ultra-fast disk
- That the manufacturer uses this parameter in a non-standard way
  that CrystalDiskInfo does not understand
- That the manufacturer used this parameter for some other purpose
  of its own, so it has nothing to do with spin-up time.

You may take your pick of the above. But in all cases, you may just
safely ignore this parameter,

Comment: "The low value means it takes too long for the hard disk to a fully operational state."
In wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes) it is indicated that a low value for the Spin-Up Time time is preferable

Comment: Yes, the question here is what constitutes a low value. I think you should rather examine the value of Spin Retry Count which indicates timeouts on spin-up.

Comment: I am concerned that this disk has been working for about 45321 hours. Therefore, additional friction could occur between the parts. Maybe such a huge parameter of spin-up time indicates this? Also, I checked the parameter of Spin Retry Count, it has an ideal value

Comment: "low value means it takes too long" most likely refers to the cooked value (where 100 or 200 is normal and lower is always worse). If it was meant to refer to the raw value, then that paragraph flat-out contradicts the previous paragraph, and so nothing on that page can be trusted.

Comment: @PavelDev: 45321 hours at 10 hours a day means more than 12 years, so that's impossible. Even at 24 hours a day this means more than 5 years. You could cross-check with  other parameters, for example Start/Stop Count, for perhaps more reliable data. You could also try another program, such as [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy).